# dplyr median by group

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have this data frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(
     Type1 = c("A","A","A", "AB", "AB"),
     Type2 = c(1L,2L,2L, 1L, 1L),
     Value = c(1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA), , Median = c(1L, 1.5, 1.5, NA, NA))
```

I would like to get median in a new column by Type1 and Type2 to a new variable "AB"  without summarise to have a new value in existing column.

```
 df12 <- data.frame(
    Type1 = c("A","A","A", "AB", "AB"),
    Type2 = c(1L,2L,2L, 1L, 1L),
    Value = c(1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA), Median = c(1L, 1.5, 1.5, 1L, 1L))
```

My try

```
df1 %>% group_by(Type1, Type2) %>% mutate(Median = ifelse(Type1 == "AB" & Type2 == 1, median(Value), Median))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to remove the grouping here

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Median = replace(Median, Type1 %in% 'AB' & Type2 %in% 1, 
        median(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) )
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a method to add a condition Type1 == "AB" & Type2 == 1? In my actual data frame is 5 times Type1 and Type2

Comment: @onhalu  i updated. that would also work. I used `is.na` because it was just a single expression