# pivot_longer: values_ptypes: can't convert <integer> to <character>

Tags: r, type-conversion, pivot, tidyr

This question is related to this question [dplyr median by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789721/dplyr-median-by-group)

and has already answers here: [pivot_longer with multiple classes causes error ("No common type")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124530/pivot-longer-with-multiple-classes-causes-error-no-common-type)

Now I have learned that we should use `values_transform` instead of `values_ptypes`.

I want to know what is the reason for this? Is there a deeper reason why `values_ptypes` does not work and `values_transform` work now:

Here is the above mentioned example that led me to this problem:

dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Type1 = c("A","A","A", "AB", "AB"),
  Type2 = c(1L,2L,2L, 1L, 1L),
  Value = c(1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA), 
  Median = c(1L, 1.5, 1.5, NA, NA))

  Type1 Type2 Value Median
1     A     1     1    1.0
2     A     2     2    1.5
3     A     2     1    1.5
4    AB     1    NA     NA
5    AB     1    NA     NA
```

I would like to `pivot_longer` using `values_ptypes` argument like this: not working!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(
     cols = contains("Type"),
     names_to = "key",
     values_to = "val", 
     values_ptypes = list(val = 'character')
     )
Error: Can't convert <integer> to <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

This should make it possible to combine `Type1` and `Type2` but it is not working.

**I want to know** why in this case I can't force type conversion.

Comment: Related: [pivot_longer with multiple classes causes error ("No common type")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124530/pivot-longer-with-multiple-classes-causes-error-no-common-type). From the top-voted accepted answer: `values_ptypes` generates an error; "Therefore I need to use the `values_transform` argument"

Comment: Thank you very much Henrik. The why and how is now solved by akrun in his answer on this question.

Comment: @TarJae The "why" is because you used the wrong argument, as described in the linked answer.

Comment: Yes you are right Henrik.  I don't want to stress it too much, but please consider that the accepted answer used `values_ptypes` and it worked; one year later the top answer noted that now `values_transform` is to be used with a guess about the "why" in the comments. This was not sufficient to answer "my why". Anyway I really appreciate  the discussion. And I am quite sure that I will remember `values_transform` now forever! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pivot_longer` needs the columns to be reshaped to have the same type.  Here 'Type1' and 'Type2' are different in `class`.  Change it to a single class by converting to `character` in `values_transform`.  According to `?pivot_longer`

> names_ptypes, values_ptypes   -  A list of column name-prototype pairs. A prototype (or ptype for short) is a zero-length vector (like integer() or numeric()) that defines the type, class, and attributes of a vector. Use these arguments if you want to confirm that the created columns are the types that you expect. Note that if you want to change (instead of confirm) the types of specific columns, you should use names_transform or **values_transform** instead.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(
     cols = contains("Type"),
     names_to = "key",
     values_to = "val", 
     values_transform = list(val = as.character))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Value Median key   val  
   <int>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1     1    1   Type1 A    
 2     1    1   Type2 1    
 3     2    1.5 Type1 A    
 4     2    1.5 Type2 2    
 5     1    1.5 Type1 A    
 6     1    1.5 Type2 2    
 7    NA   NA   Type1 AB   
 8    NA   NA   Type2 1    
 9    NA   NA   Type1 AB   
10    NA   NA   Type2 1
```

---

`pivot_longer` calls `pivot_longer_spec` and within the function the line below generates the error

```
Browse[2]> 
debug: out <- vec_c(!!!val_cols, .ptype = val_type)
Browse[2]> 
Error: Can't convert <integer> to <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: @TarJae the rror is coming from `pivot_longer_spec`.  Try `debugonce(pivot_longer_spec)` and run your code

Comment: Ooh this is fantastic master akrun. You again brought further light in my dark parts of my brain!