# How to merge one file with another with conditions on match across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements

I am stuck on what seems to be a doable task in R.   I am merging several files and am required to change the name of columns as I go to maintain the data.   There might be a better way to do that buy that is another story.   But in very simple terms I have two files dfA and dfB as below.   I need to merge the two files by "model" on dfB against EITHER column "PART1" or "PART2" or "PART3" depending on a match.

[image]

Comment: If you post a minimal example of the data someone can help you. Basically just reshape dfA from wide to long, keeping `Detail` as the relevant value, and then join the new long column with `Model`.

Comment: thank you for the information!   At one time someone showed me how within R to write code that turns my R code in to something that can be pasted here and then is reproduceable.   I can not find that.   Are you aware of this and can you help!   Sorry in advance for the lack of data so I tried to keep it way simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple yet not ideally optimal way:

```
 library("dplyr")
 dfC <- 
 union(
 union(
 left_join(dfB, dfA, by = c("Model" = "PART1")), 
 left_join(dfB, dfA, by = c("Model" = "PART2")) 
 ),
 left_join(dfB, dfA, by = c("Model" = "PART3"))
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

We could do the following:

1. Bring `dfA` into long format (note the use of the argument `values_transform` see here: [pivot_longer: values_ptypes: can't convert <integer> to <character>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790213/pivot-longer-values-ptypes-cant-convert-integer-to-character)
2. then use `right_join` by the appropriate columns and do some select:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfA %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("PART"),
    names_to = "key",
    values_to = "val", 
    values_transform = list(val = as.character)
  ) %>% 
  right_join(dfB, by=c("val"="Model")) %>% 
  select(Model=val, Detail)
```

```
  Model Detail
  <chr> <chr> 
1 A     Dog   
2 2     Cat   
3 Z     Cow
```

data:

```
dfA <- tibble(PART1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
              PART2 = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
              PART3 = c(1,2,3),
              Detail = c("Dog", "Cat", "Cow"))

dfB <- tibble(Model = c("A", "Z", 2))
```