# Change multiple columns to as.character at once

Tags: r

I want to use pivot longer on my df but not all of my columns are as.characters, as i have 10+ columns i need to change does anyone know how to do this in one argument to save me writing it out for all of the years?

My df looks like this;

```
fisheries_df
`Series Name`  `Country Name` `1997` `1998` `1999` `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010` `2011` `2012`
 1 Total fisheri… Albania        1110.8 2807.5 3057.9 3635   3597.2 4516.8 4274.6 6118.5 6473   7.71e3 7.51e3 7.36e3 8.13e3 7.85e3 7.35e3 1.23e4
 2 Total fisheri… Algeria        91907… 92620  102649 11351… 134082 13480… 141376 11405… 12662… 1.46e5 1.48e5 1.42e5 1.30e5 9.52e4 1.04e5 1.08e5
 3 Total fisheri… Cyprus         25788  20482  41060  70223  56606  142941 49561  82269  64933  3.35e4 5.65e3 5.40e3 5.11e3 5.55e3 5.85e3 5.66e3
```

the code and error message im using to pivot the df is below, assuming the character issue is my problem here;

```
fisheries_longer = pivot_longer(fisheries_df, c(3:26), c('year')) 

Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't combine `1997` <character> and `2006` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this . It is using @akruns's `values_transform()` but with list: See here: [pivot_longer: values_ptypes: can't convert <integer> to <character>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790213/pivot-longer-values-ptypes-cant-convert-integer-to-character)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(1:3),
    names_to = "key",
    values_to = "val", 
    values_transform = list(val = as.character))
```

```
   X.Series Name. X.Country key     val    
      <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>   <chr>  
 1        1 Total fisheri   Name..1 Albania
 2        1 Total fisheri   X.1997. 1110.8 
 3        1 Total fisheri   X.1998. 2807.5 
 4        1 Total fisheri   X.1999. 3057.9 
 5        1 Total fisheri   X.2000. 3635   
 6        1 Total fisheri   X.2001. 3597.2 
 7        1 Total fisheri   X.2002. 4516.8 
 8        1 Total fisheri   X.2003. 4274.6 
 9        1 Total fisheri   X.2004. 6118.5 
10        1 Total fisheri   X.2005. 6473   
# ... with 24 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

```
df <- structure(list(X.Series = 1:2, Name. = c("Total", "Total"), X.Country = c("fisheri", 
"fisheri"), Name..1 = c("Albania", "Algeria"), X.1997. = c(1110.8, 
91907), X.1998. = c(2807.5, 92620), X.1999. = c(3057.9, 102649
), X.2000. = c(3635L, 11351L), X.2001. = c(3597.2, 134082), X.2002. = c(4516.8, 
13480), X.2003. = c(4274.6, 141376), X.2004. = c(6118.5, 11405
), X.2005. = c(6473L, 12662L), X.2006. = c(7710, 146000), X.2007. = c(7510, 
148000), X.2008. = c(7360, 142000), X.2009. = c(8130, 130000), 
    X.2010. = c(7850, 95200), X.2011. = c(7350, 104000), X.2012. = c(12300, 
    108000)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that a single column/multiple columns are `character` class.  We could use `values_transform` to convert to `character` type (as `character`  and then modify if needed

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(fisheries_df, c(3:26), 'year', values_transform = as.character)
```

Or change it to `as.numeric` - if there are non-numeric elements, it will get converted to `NA`

```
pivot_longer(fisheries_df, c(3:26), 'year', values_transform = as.numeric)
```

Comment: Although this makes perfect sense (and in theory should work) my code is still giving me the same error code of; `Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't combine `1997` <character> and `2006` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @Joe Maybe it is the version difference of package as I tested this on a dummy data and it was working fine

Comment: ah ok, I also got mine to work in the end. Thanks for helping